# How to get Instagram Number of Post, Number of Followers, and Number of Following using Selenium?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Firstly I'm sorry for my poor Englih. I'm kinda new to Python. So, I would like to know on how to scrape instagram number of post, number of followers, and number of following for certain account (I try to loop at it) and store the data in CSV files.
I've been trying to figure it out the XPATH, but I thought that my XPATH already correct, so what did I miss??
Here are my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import wget
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

urls = [
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_1/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_2/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_3/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_4/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_5/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_6/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_7/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_8/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_9/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_10/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_11/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_12/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_13/',
    'https://www.instagram.com/acc_14/'
]

username_channel = []
number_of_post_chan = []
followers_chan = []
followings_chan = []
description_chan = []

#langsung buka
#collecting_data
for url in urls:
    PATH = 'C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe.'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get(url)
    #driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    #log-in
    login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']")
    login.clear()
    login.send_keys('xxxxx')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    login_pass = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='password']")
    login_pass.clear()
    login_pass.send_keys('xxxxx')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    button_login = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//form[@id='loginForm']/div/div[3]/button/div")
    button_login.click()

    time.sleep(3)
    
    #Save Your Login info?
    login_info = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='cmbtv']/button")
    login_info.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    
    usernameChan = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//h2[@class='_aacl _aacs _aact _aacx _aada']").text
    numb_of_post = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//ul[@class=' _aa_8']/li[1]/div/span").text
    followers = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class=' _aa_8']/li[2]/a/div/span").get_attribute('title')
    followings = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@class=' _aa_8']/li[3]/a/div/span").text
    description = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_aa_c']/div").text

    #username_channel.append(usernameChan)
    #number_of_post_chan.append(numb_of_post)
    #followers_chan.append(followers)
    #followings_chan.append(followings)
    #description_chan.append(description)

    print(username_channel, number_of_post_chan, followers_chan, followings_chan, description_chan)

    account_items = {
        "username_ig" : username_channel,
        "jumlah_posting" : number_of_post_chan,
        "followers" : followers_chan,
        "followings" : followings_chan,
        "deskripsi" : description_chan
    }

    driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(account_items, columns=["username_ig", "jumlah_posting", "followers", "followings", "deskripsi"])
print(df)
```

Is there any way better to express the element? Heeelp.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what error are you getting currently and on which line?

Comment: I'm getting error on defining the XPATH sir, start from numb_of_post = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//ul[@class=' _aa_8']/li[1]/div/span").text

Comment: I thought that correct based on inspect element sir, but it did not..

Comment: I try to scrape only the number sir

Answer (score 0):

To get the `username`, `number of posts`, `followers`, `following` and `description` you can select the element using `CSS_SELECTOR`.

In your code after the third `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` statement, instead of the next 5lines you can add the following.

```
usernameChan = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"h2._aacl._aacs._aact._aacx._aada").text
details = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span._ac2a._ac2b")
numb_of_post = details[0].text
followers = details[1].text
followings = details[2].text
description = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div._aacl._aaco._aacu._aacx._aad6._aade").text
```

**EDIT :** As you said, you got error while fetching details above `IndexError: list index out of range`. This probably is because the element might not have loaded until now. With the below imports replace the line where we are fetching details with the `details` in below code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

details = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span._ac2a._ac2b")))
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Himanshuman, but I got an error using your code Mr. Himanshuman, its say "numb_of_post = details[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range", what was that mean?

Comment: for the profile for which you are getting this error can you confirm if `span` with class `_ac2a _ac2b` exists

Comment: Also for which account are you getting this error, can you print the url please

Comment: yes sir, this is one of them https://www.instagram.com/officialgtvid/ and this one https://www.instagram.com/netmediatama/

Comment: @spiderboy could you please try my updated answer and let me know what you get

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is that the selector depends on whether the window is expanded or not

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).